# Can I distribute applications written using Windows 8 Developer Preview and Visual Studio 11 Express

Tags: licensing, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I've downloaded the  Windows 8 Developer Preview and have been working on some simple Metro UI application.

Can I post the source code to Github?

Is it legal to publicly distribute application written using Windows 8 Developer Preview and Visual Studio 11 Express?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You did not signed any NDA and they made this download publicly available. What Microsoft normally does not allow is to go to production with beta products and technologies.

Please, post your github url once you published your app. I would like to see it :)

Comment: additional +1 for asking for the GitHub url to check out app!

Comment: Yes, good point.  I misinterpreted the question as asking how to distribute and deploy finished apps bypassing the Store.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

You can probably pass your source code around.  No real penalty since only devs should really even have the Preview.

Maybe somebody can provide a better answer covering the Metro app redist policies and limitations (i.e. via the Store).